# System restore for new users?

Tags: 12.04, software-recommendation, restore

I am a computer repair technician, with the release of Win 8 my clients are uncomfortable with the new user interface.

I have been introducing some of them to Ubuntu (12.04). The one thing missing is system restore like in Windows 7.

I understand that there is a recovery option in grub, but I need something extremely easy for new users to use.

I found this: http://sourceforge.net/projects/system-restore/ but it hasn't seen any updates since 2009.  Any input would be helpful.

Comment: Look at LVM, it provides the means to do restore the way you want (but not the UI tools though).

Answer (score 5):

Ubuntu does not need a system restore. It is simply not applicable.

Provided that you stick to the default repositories, and to outside trusted repositories where necessary (ask on [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/) if you are unsure if a repository is trusted), your system will always work. Individual applications from outside repositories may fail, but they are dead easy to "unwind" (that's what the package manager is for).

The recovery option is there for three reasons:

1. The initial installation does not work properly, and you cannot log in normally.
2. Something goes wrong with an upgrade because of hardware problems (this is rare).
3. You enjoy messing around with your system's innards, and sometimes you mess just a little too much!

Don't worry about System Restore. Ubuntu doesn't have a Registry, and even kernel upgrades are quickly and easily unwound.

BTW, 12.04 is a good choice, being an LTS release.

Comment: Well, I once had nvidia driver somehow ruin my GRUB so that I had an empty screen and nothing else, so I'd say, at least speaking of noobs, Ubuntu does need one.

Comment: @mlvljr - The nvidia driver ruined your GRUB? That is so bizarre, it's surreal! If you have a thread about this, please post it here, because I'd love to read how it happened and how you solved it. (But, if GRUB doesn't work, you can't boot, so a system restore wouldn't work anyway; you have to restore GRUB from a Live CD.)

Comment: Well, I did a fresh Kubuntu 12.04 install, and set up the nv driver after that. Reboot -- and the screen is empty. Armed with a stack of printouts on chrooting, grub updating, reverting back to open-source drivers and nomodsetting, had a half-night fun with my laptop until got it working back (it is actually a dual-boot setup, with grub sitting on the Linux partition and EasyBCD managing the boot menu). Ok, most of the problems were rooted in me being not versed in Linuces well enough, but that's the thing -- sometimes a video driver may ruin your boot ;)

Comment: And as I somehow suspect, my memory tries to get rid of that horror, there's not much to investigate on it (left). Bizarre, indeed.

Comment: @mlvljr - when you booted to a blank screen, the chances are that it was not Grub at had been damaged. Nvidia is the screen driver, so it most likely would have been a problem with that — not Grub — that caused the blank screen. I see it quite often on [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/).

Comment: Ok, probably you're right, the only thing I managed to get on screen though were the characters "GRUB" in the top-left corner (via some weird hotkeys).